# can I use both a SQL and a NO-SQL database with Jhipster?

Tags: jhipster

I'm evaluating jhipster and it looks great.
I need *both* a MySQL and a MongoDB database.
Is there any way JHipster can generate entities for either MySQL or Mongo?

I can for sure use Spring-Data-MongoDB manually but I was wondering if even if I chose "MySQL" as my primary database I could force generation of the boilerplate code and entities for MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: no, you can't

Long answer:

- You could have 1 "MySQL" and 1 "MongoDB" project, and have some kind of micro-service architecture to access both -> that's the idea we are pushing at the moment for JHipster
- Or you could merge both project manually - it should be possible, but this is not something we have tried